# Get access token from Phonegap FaceBook plugin

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I am using the Corodova FaceBook plugin for iOS from [GitHub](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin). I have already spent many hours searching, but I have found nothing. How can I get and save the access token of the user? Later on I want to use this access token for data publishing.

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(handleStatusChange);

function handleStatusChange(session) {
  if (session.authResponse) 
      alert(session.authResponse.accessToken); // This will print the token
}
```